# AngularJS directive is not getting data passed in scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my html snippet :

```html
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
<custom-tag
title = "name"
body = "content">
</custom-tag>
</div>
```

Here is controller and directive written:

```js
var mod = angular.module("main_module",[]);

//Controller
mod.controller("ctrl",function($scope) {
  $scope.name="Page Title";
  $scope.content="sample_template.html";
  });

//Directive
mod.directive("customTag", function() {
  return {
    'restrict' : 'E',
    'scope' : {
      'title' : '=',
      'body : '='
      },
    'templateUrl' : 'directive_template.html'
    };
  });
```

```html
<!-- directive_template.html -->

<div>
  <div>{{title}}</div>
  <div ng-include="'{{body}}'"></div>
</div>
```

The actual html rendered by directive is this :

```html
<div>
  <div ng-binding></div>
  <!-- ngInclude: '{{body}}' -->
</div>
```

Clearly it is not getting the directive scope variables from attributes in `<custom_tag>`

Please tell me why it is happening and how I resolve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Your directive is named `customDirective`, but your html is `<custom-tag>`... how is any of this working at all?

Comment: Sorry I actually renamed everything here. And in actual one, I didn't do this mistake.There is something else. Directive template is loading, only scope variables are not loading.

Comment: Try using 'scope as' Syntax in the view.

Comment: How? I couldn't understand what you said

Answer (score 1):

Check the console for errors extra quotes and {{}} braces were breaking things.

```html
<div>
  <div>{{title}}</div>
  <div ng-include="body"></div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/G9JfIJGhSghUbgkKLXnV?p=preview